# How to disable read-only project files in PyCharm?

Tags: django, pycharm

I installed the Apache2 server on Kubuntu and then installed Django (2.0.4) and now all the project files are not available for editing (in PyCharm). I use the 'kate' utility to edit them with sudo. Tell me please how to disable read-only project files in PyCharm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done by regular `chown` command (Assuming you are using linux)
Try this command
`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/user/path/to/project/`

Source : [How can I become the owner of a file/folder that root owns?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40850/how-can-i-become-the-owner-of-a-file-folder-that-root-owns/40854)

Comment: Great, Dhanyavaad!